# Can you attack while prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, conditions, prone

In D&D 3.5 edition, there were penalties to armor class and attacks while you were prone. I read a *Dragon* magazine article that had a domain which allowed you to mitigate the AC penalties while prone and was thinking about how it would work in 5e.

Can you attack while prone according to the rules of 5e? If not, what would allow you to attack while prone?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can attack while prone. As it describes in the PHB's definition of the **prone** condition on page 292:

> - The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls.

So you may attack while prone, but with disadvantage.